# how to use get specified lines and append it to previous lines

Tags: sed, awk

Txt file:

```
ruby193-rubygem-sqlite3-doc.noarch  1.3.6-1.el6       rhel-x86_64-server-6-ost-3
ruby193-rubygem-test_declarative.noarch
                                    0.0.5-3.el6       rhel-x86_64-server-6-ost-3
ruby193-rubygem-test_declarative-doc.noarch
                                    0.0.5-3.el6       rhel-x86_64-server-6-ost-3
ruby193-rubygem-therubyracer.x86_64 0.11.0-0.5.beta5.el6
                                                      rhel-x86_64-server-6-ost-3
ruby193-rubygem-therubyracer-doc.noarch
                                    0.11.0-0.5.beta5.el6
                                                      rhel-x86_64-server-6-ost-3
ruby193-rubygem-thin.x86_64         1.3.1-8.el6ost    rhel-x86_64-server-6-ost-3
ruby193-rubygem-thin-doc.x86_64     1.3.1-8.el6ost    rhel-x86_64-server-6-ost-3
ruby193-rubygem-thor.noarch         0.15.4-1.el6      rhel-x86_64-server-6-ost-3
ruby193-rubygem-thor-doc.noarch     0.15.4-1.el6      rhel-x86_64-server-6-ost-3
ruby193-rubygem-tilt.noarch         1.3.3-9.el6       rhel-x86_64-server-6-ost-3
```

I want to append the 'version' to previous lines

for example:
from:

```
ruby193-rubygem-therubyracer-doc.noarch
                                    0.11.0-0.5.beta5.el6
                                                      rhel-x86_64-server-6-ost-3
```

to:

```
ruby193-rubygem-therubyracer-doc.noarch 0.11.0-0.5.beta5.el6  rhel-x86_64-server-6-ost-3
```

and leave other as default.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gawk -v RS='\0' '{ gsub ("\n\\s+", " "); print }' inputfile | column -t
```

Do you need any comments?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NF<3 {ORS=""; i+=NF} NF==3||i==3 {ORS="\n";i=0}1' input | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation:

```
awk '{$1=$1} /^ruby/{if(s)print s;s=$0;next} {s=s" "$0} END {print s}' file
```

`{$1=$1}` is used to clean extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Using xargs

```
xargs -n3 < file
```